# Changing color of given cells in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am new to android and I am trying to make a calendar with events. I want to make given cells change their color, I know I have to make a custom adapter, but I don't know how to select the cells. A short code with the getView method and little bit of explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of asking code you should show what have you tried

Comment: The problem is that I don't fully understand how to make a custom adpater, more precisley, what exactly accounts for the cell selection in the getView method. I will try something out again and I will post the code.

Comment: the getView returns the View which fills up your listview. The listview itsel manage the cell click, triggering a callback

Comment: From one of my apps, int the getView method of the adapter.  It sets the colour depending on odd or even row number but you could adapt. `view.setBackgroundColor(colours[position % colours.length]);` - colours is just `private static final int[] colours = new int[]{0x00000000,0x30808080};`

Comment: Thank you guys, Simon I will try that out now thanks